# ng-repeat, sort by smallest to highest value

Tags: angularjs

i had managed to calculate distance between user's current geo-coordinates and object geo-coordiantes, here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zsh2Bt7jBl1Z2mKKqlwa?p=preview). How can I sort `ng-repeat` from the smallest to the highest value ?. 
It is easy with the `orderBy` filter with simple expression, but this expression which prints distance is a bit tricky !thanks.

HTML:

```
  <div data-ng-controller="restaurantlistController" >


    <div  ng-repeat="restaurant in restaurantList | orderBy: 'distance'" href="#">
    <article class="item_frame">
      <div class="marker_left_container">
        <span class="venu_type_text">{{restaurant.venueType}}</span>
        <span class="distance_from_user_rest"> distance: {{distanceTo(restaurant)}}</span>
        <span class="distance_from_user_rest2">from current location</span>
      </div>
      <div class="restaurant_details_container">
        <h1 class="restaurant_name_inlist">{{restaurant.Name}}</h1>
        <span class="restaurant_detail_inlist2">{{restaurant.subCuisine}}  <br />

     {{restaurant.subsubCuisine}}</span>
        <span class="restaurant_address">{{restaurant.address}}, <br />
        </span>
        <span class="restaurant_address">{{restaurant.cp}}, {{restaurant.city}}  <br />

        </span>
        <span class="restaurant_others">{{restaurant.phoneNumber}} <br />
        </span>
        <span class="restaurant_others">{{restaurant.website}}  <br />
        </span>
        <span>-------------------------------------------------</span>
      </div>
      </div>
    </article>
    <!--main article frame 1 -->
  </div>
```

Comment: you need to write own filter i guess. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you should update the distanceTo function to the following:

```
    $scope.distanceTo = function(restaurant) {
      var distance = GreatCircle.distance( restaurant.long,restaurant.lat, position.longitude, position.latitude)
      restaurant.distance = distance;
      return distance;
    }
```

Now your filter should work, because it is checking for the restaurant.distance property.

Comment: perfect, easiest solution given out here, thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using orderBy, you could just sort the array:

```
$scope.restaurantList.sort(function(a,b) { return someDistanceFunction(a,b) } );
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just giving the `distanceTo` function as the `orderBy` predicate:

```
<div  ng-repeat="restaurant in restaurantList | orderBy:distanceTo" href="#">
```

From [orderBy documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy):

> Orders a specified array by the expression predicate.
>
> A predicate to be used by the comparator to determine the order of 
>   elements.
>
> Can be one of:
>
> - function: Getter function. The result of this function will be sorted 
>     using the <, ===, > operator.